# Facebook Graph API: Filter Facebook friends by education history

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to filter someone's facebook friends by education when you access them through the Graph API. I am trying to make it so a website displays only someone's friends who attended a certain school. Right now, I can do it by making a call to get the user's friends, then iterating through each friend, making a subsequent call and checking if their education data matches, but this seems really inefficient and takes a long time to work. Ideas? See my code below:

```
def set_up_graph
  @access_token = @facebook_cookies["access_token"]
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@access_token)
  @profile = @graph.get_object("me")
  @friends = @graph.get_connections("me","friends")
end

def find_network_friends
  @netfriends = Set.new
  @friends.each do |friend|
  id = friend["id"]
  tempf = @graph.get_object(id)
  education = tempf["education"]
  unless education == nil
    education.each do |ed|
      if ed["school"]["name"] == "Pomona College"
        @netfriends.add(id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)?

Comment: Just found that, now I'm struggling to try and pick it up. I can use this query:

"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()"

to get all my friends, but unfortunately it won't let me add "education" (and "affiliation" and "location") to the Select section. I feel like there is probably a way to do this so I'm digging into that now, any ideas?

Comment: Also, just saw that you can use multiqueries, but the only example is in PHP and I'm using Ruby, so that will take some time to figure out.